# Horizontally align table-cells within table

Tags: html, css

How can I horizontally align the text within this table-cell? It looks like it's floating to the right, and I'm not sure why. 
https://jsfiddle.net/o06e11o9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="affil2">
  <div class="oval2"></div>
  <div class="contents">
    a lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Donec facilisis tortor ut augue lacinia, at viverra est semper. Sed sapien metus, tempor a tortor.
    <br />
    <br /> Pellentesque non dignissim neque. Ut porta viverra est, ut dignissim elit elementum ut.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.affil2 {
  align-content: center;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 20;
  border: 1px solid #705A1D;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: #af9254;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
}

.contents {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 600px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.oval2 {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -110px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many strange things in your code, but for your solution you can change:

`width: 100%;` and `text-align: center;` of the class `contents`

```
.contents {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o06e11o9/1/)

Comment: I was trying a bunch of solutions, could be the result of some of the "strange stuff" but mostly I just don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: I want to keep my text in paragraph form, thats why I had it at 600px width. Should I make a child div within contents to do this? Then place the text inside that?

Comment: Ah. fixed it by padding equal on the left and the right. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.contents {
  padding-left: 200px;//hfhaunter
  padding-right: 200px;//hfhaunter
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;//thank you pablo cesar cordova morales
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```